# Remote camera with Arduino MKR GSM

Tags: gsm, camera

I'm interested in making a remote camera that could take and process still photos and send over cellular data using the Arduino MKR GSM. Is this feasible with the specs of the arduino? If it is does anyone have any suggestions of camera modules?

Comment: If you don't specify more details the answers to this are going to come down to responder's personal preferences.  E.g. how often are you taking pictures, how much data are you allowed to use, what resolution do you need etc.

Comment: Most Arduino boards don't even have enough memory to store a single still image. You might be able to get it to work, but it would be a lot of work. Get some other board, like for example the raspberry pi. Or get a cheap/old smartphone. A smartphone is probably cheaper than a board, and camera module and a GSM module combined.

Comment: Esp cam would be another option